# Highcharts not tracking mouse activity under filled area

Tags: javascript, api, highcharts, interaction

Is there any way to keep interaction on markers covered by other areas (when the do have a fill color)?

Check the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ozke/n4k57v5j/1/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    xAxis: {
        fill: '#F00',
        gridLineWidth: 1,
    },
    yAxis: {
        enabled: false,
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    series: [
        // Required JSON code?
        {
            data: [15,20,10,20,30]
        },{
            data: [10,15,20,15,20]
        },
    ]
});
```

The marker/dot in the blue area is impossible to reach/hover/interact when x=2.

In CSS, the equivalent would be using `pointer-events:none;` on the area (not the border or markers).

It's probably something to do with SVG and/or event propagation.

Comment: How about using shared tooltip? Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/n4k57v5j/2/ SVG works rather like HTML tags with `position: absolute`, so events won't get populated as you may expect: http://jsfiddle.net/n4k57v5j/3/

Comment: That would not be the same functionality but I found out a solution I just shared as an autoanswer. Thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found out there's something similar to `pointer-events: none;` for SVG (used by Highcharts). There's a few options excluse for SVG but in my case what I needed was `pointer-events: visibleStroke;`

The solution would then be:

```
path { pointer-events: visibleStroke; }
```